# memory error when todense in python using CountVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

Here is my code and memory error when call `todense()`, I am using GBDT model, and wondering if anyone have good ideas how to work around memory error? Thanks.

```
  for feature_colunm_name in feature_columns_to_use:
    X_train[feature_colunm_name] = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(X_train[feature_colunm_name]).todense()
    X_test[feature_colunm_name] = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(X_test[feature_colunm_name]).todense()
  y_train = y_train.astype('int')
  grd = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=n_estimator, max_depth=10)
  grd.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values)
```

Detailed error message,

```
in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
...
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: what is exactly the error you get?

Comment: @purpletentacle, I post the error (call stack very long, I post relevant part). Let me know if you have any good ideas. :)

Comment: Have you tried *not* using dense arrays?

Comment: @user2357112, it will not work, see here for what is wrong if not using todense => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176616/setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-error-in-scikit-learn-gradientboostingc

Comment: @LinMa: That was from trying to assign a sparse matrix to a dataframe column as if it were an array.

Comment: @user2357112, how it is related to my question posted?

Comment: By default `CountVectorizer.fit` gives sparse matrix, but when you tried to convert into dense array it takes lot of memory & if your system don't have much memory, it would through memory error

Comment: @Kalsi, nice catch. But if you refer to this discussion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176616/setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-error-in-scikit-learn-gradientboostingc), you can find it seems GradientBoostingClassifier only works with dense other than sparse?

Comment: How much memory does your system have? and what is the theoretical size of the array (i.e., what are the dimensions of `X_train` and `X_test`)?

Comment: Check the `presort ` parameter of [GradientBoostingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.fit). So it does support sparse input. May be you need to downscale the data.(because of your system limitations) You can also try [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong here:

```
for feature_colunm_name in feature_columns_to_use:
    X_train[feature_colunm_name] = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(X_train[feature_colunm_name]).todense()
    X_test[feature_colunm_name] = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(X_test[feature_colunm_name]).todense()
```

1) You are trying to assign mutliple columns (result of `CountVectorizer` will be a 2-d array where columns represent features) to a single column '`feature_colunm_name`' of DataFrame. Thats not going to work and will produce error.

2) You are fitting the CountVectorizer again on the test data, which is wrong. You should use the same CountVectorizer object on test data that you used on trainind data and only call `transform()`, not `fit_transform()`.

Something like:

```
cv = CountVectorizer()
X_train_cv = cv.fit_transform(X_train[feature_colunm_name])
X_test_cv = cv.transform(X_test[feature_colunm_name])
```

3) `GradientBoostingClassifier` works well with sparse data. Its not mentioned in documentation yet (seems like a mistake on the documentation).

4) You seem to be transforming multiple columns of your original data to bag-of-words form. For that you will need to use those many CountVectorizer objects and then merge all the output data into a single array which you pass to GradientBoostingClassifier.

**Update**:

You need to setup something like this:

```
# To merge sparse matrices
from scipy.sparse import hstack

result_matrix_train = None
result_matrix_test = None

for feature_colunm_name in feature_columns_to_use:
    cv = CountVectorizer()
    X_train_cv = cv.fit_transform(X_train[feature_colunm_name])

    # Merge the vector with others
    result_matrix_train = hstack((result_matrix_train, X_train_cv)) 
                          if result_matrix_train is not None else X_train_cv

    # Now transform the test data
    X_test_cv = cv.transform(X_test[feature_colunm_name])
    result_matrix_test = hstack((result_matrix_test, X_test_cv)) 
                         if result_matrix_test is not None else X_test_cv
```

Note: If you have other columns also which you did not process through the Countvectorizer because they are already numerical or so, which you want to merge with the `result_matrix_train`, you can do that too by:

```
result_matrix_train = hstack((result_matrix_test, X_train[other_columns].values)) 
result_matrix_test = hstack((result_matrix_test, X_test[other_columns].values))
```

Now use these to train:

```
...
grd.fit(result_matrix_train, y_train.values)
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek, could you elaborate a bit more what means "merge all the output data into a single array"?