# Convert each document to a vector based on TF -IDF

Tags: pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, plot, tf-idf

I have written the code below that is calculating the TF-IDF score

```
docs=['ali is a good boy',
      'a good boy is not bad',
      'ali is not bad but bad is good']

cv=CountVectorizer()

# this steps generates word counts for the words in your docs
word_count_vector=cv.fit_transform(docs)
print(word_count_vector)
tfidf_transformer=TfidfTransformer(smooth_idf=True,use_idf=True)
tfidf_transformer.fit(word_count_vector)

# print idf values
df_idf = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_transformer.idf_, index=cv.get_feature_names(),columns=["idf_weights"])
# sort ascending
df_idf.sort_values(by=['idf_weights'])

# count matrix
count_vector=cv.transform(docs)
# tf-idf scores
tf_idf_vector=tfidf_transformer.transform(count_vector)
feature_names = cv.get_feature_names()
print(feature_names)
#get tfidf vector for first document
first_document_vector=tf_idf_vector[0]
#for first_document_vector in tf_idf_vector:
#print the scores
df=(pd.DataFrame(first_document_vector.T.todense().transpose(),columns=feature_names))
df.to_csv('file1.csv')
```

1- In the end i am able to get the vector of first document. But i ma not able to get the vector for all documents. I tried looping through and appending to dataframe but it didnt work.
2- how can I save the index of document in csv file?
I have to run it on movies plot from movie Lens dataset. This is why it is important for me to save the index of documnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the vector for all documents:

```
#get tfidf vector for all documents
all_document_vector = tf_idf_vector
df= pd.DataFrame(all_document_vector.T.todense().transpose(),columns=feature_names)
```

To export a csv file with Index:

```
df.to_csv('file1.csv',index=True, index_label = 'Index')
```

Comment: Thanks @manojk , I tried the code you suggested, But I get memory error. What can I do to avoid it

Comment: There could be multiple reasons for the memory error to occur, try changing the `df= pd.DataFrame(all_document_vector.T.todense().transpose(),columns=feature_names)` to `df= pd.DataFrame(all_document_vector.T.toarray().transpose(),columns=feature_names)` if that helps or you can use [HashingVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html) which uses low memory.

Comment: same issue with toarray(). I cant use the HashingVectorizer. as it has limitations which are listed on documentation page https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html

Comment: Try limiting the words count with `max_features`. Are you using a 32 Bit system? There are some solutions given here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194375/memory-error-when-todense-in-python-using-countvectorizer)